# Importing images results to wrong folder structure

Tags: images, import

I imported ~10GB of images from my old wordpress.com site to the new server. Most things work fine, but on appr. 5%, the image is uploaded to a wrong folder.

I.e. the page refers to "uploads/2017/03/test.jpg" but the file is saved in "uploads/2017/02/test.jpg". There is no real logic behind this, sometimes the folder is a month too early, sometimes too late..

So the images are saved into a wrong folder.

How can I fix this without manually transferring 400 images and changing their database entry?